# Is there a way to isolate logging with NLog?

Tags: c#, nlog

We have an application in .NET Framework 4.7.1 that uses NLog. We have mostly ported this to .NET 5. The main purpose of this application is to run tests on our hardware with up to 4 tests that could be run simultaneously. In the .NET Framework version of the application we spun up app domains for each test. This ended up working out well for us because we wanted to log pretty much everything that happened in each test to their own files. Now, with the removal of app domains in .NET 5, we'd like to keep the same logging isolation that app domains provide.

Currently, without the isolation of app domains, all of the logging information is logged to all targets.

So, without the isolation that app domains provided, is there another solution that could work?

I've attached a diagram that (hopefully) provides more clarity about what we're trying accomplish.

I tried filtering based on the logger name, but other libraries / classes (and there's a lot) use LogManager.GetCurrentClass, and that obviously gets another logger. I've also tried filtering by a thread id, but that has the same issue.

[Flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv0MF.png)

Comment: The FileName of NLog FileTarget can be controlled by [context](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context). Maybe use `Logger.PushScopeProperty("TestName", mytest)` and include [${scopeproperty:TestName:whenEmpty=App}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ScopeProperty-Layout-Renderer) in the NLog FileTarget FileName.

Comment: That did work for a single instance of a class. Is there a way to get the same result with multiple instances of the same class? I ended up creating separate log factory instances for that scenario, which is a workable solution. I'm curious if there's another solution.

I have another question that's related: is it possible to isolate logging of classes that were created in a test to log to only the test that created it? I can edit my original post with example code or create a separate one if it helps any.

Comment: If you create isolated LogFactory for each "test"-run, then you can assign NLog-Configuration-Variable with the test-name, and then update NLog FileTarget FileName to include `${var:TestName}`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Var-Layout-Renderer